# Read Cassandra SSTable files

Tags: cassandra

By what means can I read the data from a Cassandra SSTable data file and ignore it's rows expire date?

My data is stored with ~18 months TLT, however I've got a complete backup and want to read data older than 18 months.

If I restore the backed data to a Cassandra instance and try select it, it will only retrieve me not expired rows.

I even thought sstable2json (my production instance is 2.2) would just read the entire file, however it only brought me not expired data as well.

For some reasons I need to retrieve expired data (realtime is not a requirement). Is there any library or gist or sample code that allows me to read the whole SSTable file? I need a way to automate it, maybe with Java or Python or Golang, anything.

PS.: I know the data is there 'cause I read it manually (`cat file-Data.db | unpigz | less`)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the TTLRemover project. It essentially does what you look for: Remove the TTL marker from SSTables. When it was written, it was against Cassandra 2.2, so it should work for you.

https://github.com/instaclustr/TTLRemover